# Allow admins (not owners) to create repos in Github

Tags: github

Is it possible to limit who can create repositories in a Github organization. From this article: https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.14/user/articles/restricting-repository-creation-in-your-organization it seems like the options are basically owners or everyone. Is there a middle ground?

Making someone a Github owner is a serious permission so we really don't want to give that out just so that someone can make a repo. On the other hand allowing everyone in the organization the ability (contractors, non-technical, read-only roles) the permission to make repos seems too broad.

Has anyone come up with a better solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be to setup a [webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/).

That means having a listener for a [repository event](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#repositoryevent), which does include the owner: If said owner is not part of an admin list, the listener could:

- send back an email to the owner of the newly created repostory, explaining that creation has been denied
- delete the repository ([through the GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#delete-a-repository))